# ClassNotFoundException android.view.scrollview when Inflating view

Tags: android, xml, listview, popup, scrollview

I'm trying to inflate a view containing a scrollview and i get a ClassNotFoundException android.view.scrollview when Inflating view on the following line:

View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_article, null, true);

I cannot find anything wrong myself and googling the issue didn't help me (unfortunatly).

On the other hand, this is actually also a workaround for something I don't know how to do.

Situation:
I've got a tab layout with 3 tabs. In each tab, I've got a listview containing a news-item. When I click on the news-item, I want the listview layout to be switched with the xml layout i'm now using for the popup (it's kinda cheating, but I don't know how to do it properly). So if anybody has a way to do this instead of using a popup, it will be the best answer for me.

**Method where I inflate the layout:**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) 
{
   //setContentView(R.layout.news_article);
   final PopupWindow popUp;
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)NewsActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
   View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_article, null, false);
   Display display  =GetWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
   int popUpWidth = display.getWidth();
   int popUpHeight = display.getHeight();

   popUp = new PopupWindow(layout,  popUpWidth, popUpHeight, true); 
   popUp.setOutsideTouchable(true);                     

   popUp.setTouchInterceptor(new OnTouchListener()
   {
      @Override
      public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
      {
        System.out.println("Touch Intercepted");
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE)
        { 
             popUp.dismiss();
        }
            return false;
      }
   });

   popUp.showAtLocation(getListView(), Gravity.TOP, 0, 75);
}
```

**XML code for the layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Scrollview
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/news_article_scroll"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffffff">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/news_article_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src = "@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_article_header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/news_article_icon"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news_article_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/news_article_icon"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="Text" />

</RelativeLayout>
</Scrollview>
```

**********EDIT*****************
Ok, the popup now shows, but I'm not receiving any events from it

Comment: Should be ScrollView, not Scrollview.  Capitalize the v

Comment: I totally missed that typo, thanks! The popup still doesn't show, but I might be able to make progress now.

Answer (score 2):

I tried it in my code and it works when I change Scrollview to ScrollView in the xml file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

</ScrollView>
```

The xml is correct if you write it with a small 'v' but the inflater does not recognize it and requires a capital 'V'.

You can see that very easily when you put a try catch block around it and check the exception because it says it there.

Comment: No he didn't! news_article is the name of the layout-file and news_article_scroll the id of the HorizontalScrollView!

Answer (score 0):

When you inflate your layout you set no parentView, but you set the flag `true`

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_article, null, true);
```

Set the flag to false and add the view where you need it.

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_article, null, false); 
myParentViewGroup.add(layout);
```

Comment: When I try this I get the following error: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView. Seems like you cannot add something to a ListView?